# How to get user home of local machine not the user home of tomcat server where is running?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a Spring boot app and I deployed it on Tomcat server on windows server 2019, the problem is when I want to download and generate excel from app, tomcat saves it under windows server not in local machine.
but I want to download that excel on my local machine not on server side.

please help me ............... thank you!!!

this is my code :

```
@GetMapping("/generatePetitionExcel/{application}/{dateStart}/{dateEnd}")
    public String generatorPetitionExcel(@PathVariable(required = false, name = "application") String requestApplication,
            @PathVariable(required = false, name = "dateStart") Date  requestStart,
            @PathVariable(required = false, name = "dateEnd") Date  requestEnd) throws IOException {
        System.out.println(" ---------------- i'm here :: 1 -------------------");
        List<PetitionDTO> petition = petitonService.findPetitionInProgress(requestApplication, requestStart, requestEnd);
        System.out.println(" -****** petition.siz() == " +petition.size());
        JExcelHelper generatorExcel = new JExcelHelper();
        System.out.println("[excel_1]::");
        String chemin = System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Downloads";
        String excelFilePath =chemin+"\\SEGUIMIENTO_PETICIONES -"+formatter1.format(requestStart)+"-"+formatter1.format(requestEnd)+".xls";         
        System.out.println("[excel_2]::");
        String ret = generatorExcel.writeExcel(petition,excelFilePath);
        System.out.println("[excel_3]::");
        return ret;
    }
```

Comment: That is obviously not going to work. You will need to write to the `OutputStream` of the response so that it can be downloaded.

Comment: @M.Deinum       try (FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(excelFilePath)) {
      System.out.println(" ---------------- i'm here :: 4 -------------------");
         workbook.write(outputStream);
         ret= "Excel generate Successfuly";
     }catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(""+e.getMessage());
      ret="test incorect ";
  }

Comment: @M.Deinum It works but  download goes to Tomcat server where it is running on windows server 2019, but I want to download on my local machine client side

Comment: No it isn't downloading anything it is writing a file to the local filesystem. It isn't a download. You need to write to the outputstream of the response **not** a `FileOutputStream`. From the server there is no way you can access the local filesystem from the client that is calling you .